# Angular, pass current object in repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

trying to pass the object you are clicking on to a function (in an ng-repeat) and it doesn't seem to be working how I thought it would. Here's the code in the directive:

```
  <md-item ng-repeat="item in model" >
   <md-item-content >
      <div class="md-tile-left">
      </div>
      <div class="md-tile-content" ng-click="updateFn(item)">
         <h3>ID: {{item.id}}</h3>
         <h4>Type: {{item.type}}</h4>
         <h4>Version: {{item.metadata.version}}</h4>
         <h4>State: {{item.metadata.state}}</h4>
      </div>
   </md-item-content>
   <md-divider layout-fill></md-divider>
   </md-item-content>
</md-item>
```

The directive looks like so:

```
 function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            controller: TreeCtrl,
            scope: {
                model: '=',
                updateFn: '&'
            },
            templateUrl: 'template.html'
        };
```

using the directive like so :

```
<div vit-tree model="data" update-fn="updateFn(item)">
```

And the function it is returning to right now just looks like :

```
 $scope.updateFn = function(item){
                console.log(item);
```

The directive is rendering fine, accepting the correct data, and the updateFn is firing correctly, it's just coming back undefined.

I want it to sent he current object (item) into the function, when i log it currently, it's undefined. Thanks!

Comment: please show us your `model.relationships.child`

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: @Ahmad added all I am using. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're calling a function from the directive you need to create a correspondence between the call and the declaration of the function when using the directive. So, in your case you declared it here:

```
<div vit-tree model="data" update-fn="updateFn(item)">
```

And, when you actually call it here,

```
 <div class="md-tile-content" ng-click="updateFn(item)">
```

you need to create an object to tell angular what to use on the previous declaration. In your case:

```
 <div class="md-tile-content" ng-click="updateFn({'item': item})">
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't pass the item itself but you should be able to pass the id and handle it in the controller:

```
  <md-item ng-repeat="item in model" >
   <md-item-content >
      <div class="md-tile-left">
      </div>
      <div class="md-tile-content" ng-click="updateFn(item.id)">
         <h3>ID: {{item.id}}</h3>
         <h4>Type: {{item.type}}</h4>
         <h4>Version: {{item.metadata.version}}</h4>
         <h4>State: {{item.metadata.state}}</h4>
      </div>
   </md-item-content>
   <md-divider layout-fill></md-divider>
   </md-item-content>
</md-item>
```

Comment: hmm.. still coming back undefined

Comment: so post your full code or provide a fiddle so we can help you more